# How to map detached Collection(List, Set) or Map with Hibernate via annotations

Tags: java, hibernate

I know, that there is a way to map Map via XML:

```
 <set name="images"
 table="ITEM_IMAGE"
 order-by="IMAGENAME asc">
 <key column="ITEM_ID"/>
 <composite-element class="Image">
 <property name="name" column="IMAGENAME" not-null="true"/>
 <property name="filename" column="FILENAME" not-null="true"/>
 <property name="sizeX" column="SIZEX" not-null="true"/>
 <property name="sizeY" column="SIZEY" not-null="true"/>
 </composite-element>
</set>
```

Is there way to do the same thing via annotations mapping, and how to persist it into separate table?

Thatks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For composite values or basic types it should be almost the same, first you need to tell hibernate that we are mapping to a collection 
then specify the name of the table which should hold your map and the join column with your current entity , then you specify the key.

```
         @Entity
         public class Item {
              @Id
              @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
              @Column(name = "Item_ID")
               private Long itemId;

              @ElementCollection
              @CollectionTable(name="ITEM_IMAGE",     joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="ITEM_ID"))
              @MapKeyColumn(name="ITEM_ID")
              private Map<String, Image> contacts = new HashMap<String, Image>();
              }

              @Embeddable
              public class Image {
               //Specify your composite attributes with the column name for each
              }
```

hope I did not miss anything

Comment: Thanks, but how should I persist this Map into my database?
Should I put it into some entity, or there is a way to persist it in other way?

Comment: it should be in the entity which has this list,( the enitity with primary key ITEM_ID)

Comment: Would you be so kind to write full example for me?